# Counterexample for the infinitely many primes between two primes in a Noetherian ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Consider the following Proposition:

**Proposition:** Let $R$ be a noetherian ring.  If $p_0 \subsetneq p_1 \subsetneq p_2$ is a chain of distinct prime ideals in $R$, then there exist infinitely many distinct primes $q$ such that $p_0 \subsetneq q \subsetneq p_2$.

For a proof, see for instance [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/798375/193613) question.  I would like to see a counterexample if we drop the noetherian hypothesis.  Should such a ring exists I would find it rather interesting because it would be an example where a "finiteness" hypothesis implies that there are infinitely many of something!

Comment: today almost a same question was asked. you can see it here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040186/ring-with-nested-prime-ideals

Comment: That does it, thanks. My apologies for missing that my question was already asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a non-noetherian valuation ring of rank two. For such an example you can take a look at [Examples of Non-Noetherian Valuation Rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363166/examples-of-non-noetherian-valuation-rings/693021#693021).